# How do GPU handle indirect branches

Tags: gpu

My understanding of GPUs is that they handle branches by executing all path while suspending instances that are not supposed to execute the path. This works well for if/then/else kind of construct and loops (instance that terminated the loop can be suspended until all instance are suspended).

This flat out does not work if the branch is indirect. But modern GPUs (Fermi and beyond for nVidia, not sure when it appear for AMD, R600 ?) claim to support indirect branches (function pointers, virtual dispatch, ...).

Question is, what kind of magic is going on in the chip to make this happen ?

Comment: AFAIK, NVIDIA GPUs are the only ones that support indirect branching. I've tried getting more info by bribing some of their engineers but failed so far :)

Comment: Found something : http://www.google.com/patents/US7761697

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PTX ISA >=6.0 has indirect branches via jump tables with `bra.idx` instruction.

Unlike the regular `if (a == 2) { ... } else { ... }` code (as well as `switch (...) { ... }`), the `brx.idx` solution avoids multiple `setp.ne.s32` comparisons:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

#if (defined(_MSC_VER) && defined(_WIN64)) || defined(__LP64__) || defined(__CUDACC_RTC__)
#define __LDG_PTR "l"
#else
#define __LDG_PTR "r"
#endif /*(defined(_MSC_VER) && defined(_WIN64)) || defined(__LP64__) || defined(__CUDACC_RTC__)*/

__global__ void kernel(uint32_t* tgt)
{
        printf("tgt = %d\n", *tgt);
        asm volatile(".reg .u32 r_tgt;");
        asm volatile("ld.u32 r_tgt, [%0];" :: __LDG_PTR(tgt));
        asm volatile("ts: .branchtargets BLK0, BLK1, BEXIT;");
        asm volatile("brx.idx r_tgt, ts;");
        asm volatile("BLK0:");
        printf("BLK0\n");
        asm volatile("ret;\n");
        asm volatile("BLK1:");
        printf("BLK1\n");
        asm volatile("ret;\n");
        asm volatile("BEXIT:");
        printf("BEXIT\n");
        asm volatile("ret;\n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        uint32_t* tgt = nullptr;
        cudaMalloc(&tgt, sizeof(uint32_t));
        uint32_t val = atoi(argv[1]);
        printf("Testing tgt = %d\n", val);
        cudaMemcpy(tgt, &val, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        kernel<<<1, 1>>>(tgt);
        auto err = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        if (err != cudaSuccess)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "CUDA error: code = %d\n", err);
                exit(-1);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Full example in [Gist](https://gist.github.com/dmikushin/2b4faba0d160ce40074bc53f6f063a0a).

Answer (score 2):

Accordingly to the Cuda programming guide there is some strong restrictions on virtual functions and dynamic dispatching.

See http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#functions for more information. Another interesting article about how code is mapped to the GPU hardware is http://yosefk.com/blog/simd-simt-smt-parallelism-in-nvidia-gpus.html .

Answer (score 1):

GPUs are like CPUs in regards to indirect branches. They both have an IP (instruction pointer) that points to physical memory.  This IP is incremented for each hardware instruction that gets executed. An indirect branch just sets the IP to the new location.  How this is done is a little bit more complicated. I will use PTX for Nvidia and GCN Assembly for AMD.

An AMD GCN GPU can have its IP simply set from any register. Example: "s_branch S8" The IP can be set with any value. In fact, on an AMD GPU, its possible to write to the program memory in a kernel and then set the IP to execute it (self modifying code).

On NVidia's PTX there is no indirect jump. I have been waiting for real hardware indirect branch support since 2009. The most current version of the PTX ISA 4.3 still does not have indirect branching.  In the current PTX ISA manual, http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution, it still reads that "Indirect branch is currently unimplemented".

However, "[indirect calls](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/525303/cuda-programming-and-performance/is-dynamic-code-generation-possible-/post/3719542/#3719542)" are supported via jump tables. These are slightly different then indirect branches but do the same thing. I did some testing with jump tables in the past and the performance was not great. I believe the way this works is that the kernel is lunched with a table of already known call locations. Then when it runs across a "call %r10(params)" (something like that) it saves the current IP and then references the jump table by an index and then sets the IP to that address. I'm not 100% sure but its something like that.

Like you said, besides branching both AMD and NVidia GPUS also allow instructions to be executed but ignored. It executes them but does not write the output. This is another way of handing an if/then/else as some cores are ignored while others run. This does not really have much to do with branching. This is a trick to just avoid a time consuming branches. Some CPUs like the Intel Itanium also do this.

You can also try searching under these other names also: Indirect Calls, Indirect Branches, Dynamic branching, virtual functions, function pointers or jump tables

Hope this helps. Sorry I went so long.